# Need guidance on two-dimensional lookup

Tags: excel, lookup-tables, name-lookup

I have a workbook with two worksheets. On the first worksheet titled "Report", I want to get data from my second worksheet, titled "DataSets". Ideally, I would like to have three or four tables on DataSets, and in Report I would like to be able to get the values at the intersections.

I noticed when using tables, "Test1" does not display if I enter =Data1[]. I can't use defined names because the titles of the rows and columns are the same.

My "DataSets" worksheet looks like this:

[image]

Is there another way I should be attempting to do this that will allow similarly titled rows and columns but in different blocks of data?

Comment: @pnuts         I never said that the data was the same. Aside from that, the data being split among different tables is simply a requirement.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you want Report to look like. You should be able to do a two-dimensional lookup using Index/Match, but without seeing the hoped-for result I can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like that:

```
=INDEX(([firsttabrange],[secondtabrange],...),MATCH(A3,[rowheader],0),MATCH(A2,[columnheader],0),MATCH(A1,{"Data1","Data2",...},0))

A1 = TableName (upper left Cell)
A2 = ColumnName (asuming all tables have the same names, just pick one)
A3 = RowName (like ColumnName)
```

Note: either do it for the whole table (always start at the TableName-Cell    for all ranges or never do it)

if you need it to compare values, do it 1 time for each table but leave the tablename out, like:

```
 =INDEX([firsttabrange],MATCH(A3,[rowheader],0),MATCH(A2,[columnheader],0))
```

Do the same for each other table

Hint2: set a proper data validation for `A1`, `A2` and `A3` helps a lot at picking the data you want

however... i'm not sure if that is what you are looking for